# Selecting If One Row From Entity Exists in Symfony / Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am making a web app using Symfony 4.

The app has (among others) a User entity, Post entity, and a PostLike entity. A user can create many posts, and a post can have many likes. So PostLike references User and Post. Below is my PostLike entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostLikeRepository")
 */
class PostLike
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="postLikes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="postLikes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $post;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id): void
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $user
 */
public function setUser($user): void
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPost()
{
    return $this->post;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $post
 */
public function setPost($post): void
{
    $this->post = $post;
}

public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}
}
```

When I am on the view page for an individual post, how would I reference whether a user has liked this post in TWIG? This will be the ‘many’ side of the relationship, but I just need one row (if it exists), and I’m not sure how to do this...

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you can check whether such PostLike with such user and post exist or not and pass it to the view:

```
$liked = false;
$postLike = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:PostLike')->findOneBy(['user'=>$user->getId(),'post'=>$post->getId()]);
if($postLike !== null){
$liked = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but my reputation is only 12 currently :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply show whether `Likes` exist you can add a field to the Post entity:

```
public function hasLikes()
{
    return (0 === count($this->likes)) ? false : true;
}
```

and include in twig something like `{% if post.hasLikes %}Liked{% endif %}`.

You could do something similar with a count and a badge to show the number of likes.